# Making vertex at intersection points of lines from two layers using QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I have 2 layers of polylines representing a two road network called roads and routeir (Loaded to Qgis from 2 shapefiles). I want to insert vertices at the intersection points between the two polylines (where the purple polylines cross the red polyline).

How can I achieve this in QGIS?

I am **not** interested in adding a geometric point at intersection points.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yep, I have turned off the intersections layers. It's basically using line intersection which creates a geometric point at the intersection. This is not what I am interested in. By 'make vertex' i mean to insert a vertex to one or both the polyline layers.

Comment: Do you want your lines split at the point of crossing or unsplit but "snapped" to each other's vertex at the crossing?  I'm in the middle of reinstalling QGIS but I think there is a SAGA tool in the QGIS processing toolbox (if you installed it) to split lines at points, and there is a QGIS tool to snap to points (geometries to layer), so you could use the points from your intersection in either of the other tools and see if either works for you.

Comment: Hi John, Nope I don't want the lines split. If you mean snapping as to insert a vertex at the point of intersection, yes that what I want. I also included another picture to clarify the problem better.

Comment: Did you try the snap geometries tool, snapping each line layer to the points you created in the intersection, using a very small tolerance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In QGIS 3 open the processing toolbox and use either

- [Vector Overlay -> Line Intersections](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#line-intersections) to create a new point layer with the intersections between the two Polyline layers, or
- [Vector Overlay -> Split with lines](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#split-with-lines) to create vertices in the `Input layer` where it is intersected by the `Split layer`.

Answer (score 1):

Tried the "Vector overlay -> Split with lines" in QGIS 3.12 and the output layer doesn't have the additional vertices. I ended up using "SAGA Split lines with lines" and I get what I expected.

1. Input is a line vector layer with 4 line features.
2. Split is a merged line vector layer with 10ish line features.
3. Ran SAGA tool.
4. Extracted vertices from output layer - has original points and intersection points.